# Split Action Bar with AppCompat v7 using Material Design?

Tags: android, material-design

Is it possible to have the App Compat ActionBar split when targeting API 21?

Right now I have had all activities include

```
 android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
```

and have meta-data:

```
 <meta-data android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS"
            android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />
```

And my theme Base is Theme.AppCompat

but for some reason this has absolutely no effect making the action bar split.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no split action bar support for Material themes or AppCompat v21. You can certainly create your own bottom action bar via a [Toolbar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html) added to your layout, but you have to manage combining the controls on >600dp configurations yourself.

Comment: OKay, just wanted to make sure of this. I guess this is what I will have to do. Thanks

Comment: May be it is better to use the ActionMenuView. It is the same widget used by the Toolbar to show the actions.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti - yep! You could certainly use an `ActionMenuView`. one thing that `Toolbar` gives you in addition is support for setting a theme via XML using `app:theme` and `app:popupTheme`.